# Should I put this in a separate tab?

Tags: tabs

I am currently developing an IPython launcher written in PyQt. I am creating the UI layout with Qt Designer, but I have a question. Should I keep the log in the same tab or in a different tab? I've been thinking. (Ooh! I should keep it in a different tab for more space! But then it'll be less convenient. Ooh! Keep in the same tab for more convenience. But then it'll be smaller)

Here are the pictures:

Figure 1 - same tab:

[image: same tab]

Figure 2 - different tab:

[image: different tab]

Comment: What is this log used for? Or the control panel either?  It's hard to say how to organise your UI without explaining what these features are used for, by whom and how frequently.

Comment: @JonW Read my comments on Anenth's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If users really care about the log and if they **frequently** visit this window to see the log, then it's better to have a **separate tab**, so that user can visit the information easier.

It's **not about convenience**, it's about the user's **[mental model](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/mental-models/)** and how user's mental model matches the UI.

Comment: You're probably right, but I need upvotes for your answer to accept it.

Comment: My vision is for the user to start the notebook server, then use it in their browser or the built-in browser in-app. I think if they see something go wrong, they should go to the logs and check it. If they need to _do anything_ to the notebook server/IPython, they use the GUI.

Comment: Conceptually, tabs are supposed to represent related information, or different views of the same information (though they frequently get used for things other than that). So I agree with @Anenth .   https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=wNozxtKuOKcC&pg=PA103&lpg=PA103&dq=tabs+different+views+same+information&source=bl&ots=v767mazar0&sig=o2lQXEzZm1PZyvYTW_-0XhRs_2k&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWp-u6ku_JAhXBtBoKHYc8AVgQ6AEIMzAE#v=onepage&q=tabs%20different%20views%20same%20information&f=false